# MFMailComposeViewController leaks?

Tags: objective-c

The following code leaks whenever I send email, and I do not know what to change. There are people saying online that MFMailComposeViewController leaks, but it is kind of unbelievable that the leak was never fixed.

Any idea, what might be wrong with the following code, or confirm that MFMailComposeViewController leaks.

```
- (void) email {
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {

MFMailComposeViewController *mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;

[mailViewController setToRecipients:[[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"123@123.com", nil] autorelease]];
[mailViewController setSubject:@"Contact us"];
[self presentModalViewController:mailViewController animated:YES];
[mailViewController release];
} else {
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cannot send email" 
                                                message:@"Please check your email setting" 
                                               delegate:nil 
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
}
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Looks good. You can try to use arrayWithObjects, but I guess it won't affect on this. What tool shows a leak?

Comment: one note - setToRecipients takes NSArray, no reason to create mutable version

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with that code. If you're seeing a leak in an app with just that in it then I suggest filing a radar for it with specific instructions for what steps cause the leak.

On another note I would change the settings of recipients line to this:

```
[mailViewController setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"123@123.com"]];
```

Comment: Nice use of the convenience class, that suggestion alone is worth a +1.